# How to get the values of all the Properties in an SP Feature

Tags: powershell, feature, properties

I'm trying to see all the values in a particular SP Feature. I've been trying to do so with Powershell as follows.

```
Get-SPFeature MessageServer | Select -Property Properties
```

Though all that seems to show is the names of the properties. I know there values associated with those properties but I'm not sure how to get them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code, it will print value of the each feature properties in console.

```
$feature  = Get-SPFeature MessageServer
$feature.Properties | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$($_.Name) - $($_.Value) "}
```

Comment: Yes that  does what I want. Thankyou!

Comment: also just
&feature.Properties 
seems to do a print out similar to that.